# Export 16.10 internal error reporting to a file

Tags: 16.10, error-handling

Does somebody knows how I can export an error box that my computer shows everyday to a file? I'm running 16.10-64bit and I tried Copying and pasting, but the box allows copying just topic-by-topic. 
The error I wanna deal with has more than 30 topics!!!! I tried to post an image, but it's not allowed to me.
The box has a following message at top: "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.10 has experienced an internal error."
Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the dialogue box that eventually asks you to send an error report to canonical ?

Comment: Yes, but in my case is not eventual, I received it everytime I log in my session.

Comment: First click on more detail to see why this error occurs, at times it might just a trivial issues from an app. If more than that look for a solution on the web or here and send the report. Such error messages should be in the log files.

Comment: Ok, but where this kind of error report is stored? Look that my question is not to specific error, but to the app that 'theorically' send reports to Canonical (I dunno if Canonical receives these reports...) maybe it's apport.

Comment: They should as their developers will need it to see if the issue is a bug as they compare it to other such reports they receive.

Comment: They are in `/var/log`, but not some apps have specific log files but some others don't.

Comment: Very well.. following your suggestion, I run "grep -r '/opt/java/bin/java' /var/log/*",  then I found error message in apport.log.1... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Following [George](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george) hint, I executed this command:

```
sudo grep -r '/opt/java/bin/java' /var/log/*
```

then I found the error messages in /var/log/apport.log.1